# Random walks of length $2n$

Tags: combinatorics, random-walk, reflection

I have the question:

> Show that the number of walks of length $2n$ that start at $(0, 0)$ and do not touch the $x$-axis is equal to the number of walks of length $2n$ that hit $0$ at time $2n$.

I have that the number of walks of length $2n$ from $(0,0)$ to $(2n,0)$ is $2n$ Choose $n$. However I don't know where to progress here, I have the positive walks theorem and this need to be multiplied by $2$ to include all walks that are strictly negative but I cant seem to find a proof of this theorem.

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Not following.  If you start at $(0,0)$ you have already touched the $x$-axis.  What are the possible steps in your walk?

Comment: Your question is not clear.  If you mean the usual sort of random walk (as in counting $\#Heads-\#Tails$ in a string of coin tosses) then from $(0,0)$ you can only walk to $(1,\pm1)$.  There are no paths from $(0,0)$ to $(0,2n)$.  If you mean some other sort of random walk...well, you have to describe it.  Perhaps you could show us how it works for $n=1$.  Whatever your definition is, the case of two steps can't be difficult.

Comment: @lulu sorry the question is unclear it is how our lecturer has worded it which is why I think I am struggling to understand it. Here the random walks are up/down steps that have equal probability.
 Im sorry I realised I made a mistake in the question I meant $(2n,0) $ as in it returns to the point 0 at time 2n. but for the first part it is that it starts at the origin and does not return to touching the x axis

Comment: Ok.  This is known as the [Positive Walks Theorem](http://www.math.unl.edu/~sdunbar1/ProbabilityTheory/Lessons/BernoulliTrials/PositiveWalks/positivewalks.pdf) and the proof can be found in that link.

Comment: @lulu thanks for your help, although I don't think that proof is correct because it doesn't actually conclude the result that the theorem states.

Comment: Yes, it does.  It phrases it as a statement in probability but it's the same claim.  There are $2^{2n}$ total paths so each path has probability $\frac 1{2^{2n}}$.

Comment: @lulu I know that you need to multiply it by 2^2n to have the total number of walks, but if you follow the proof it proves that the total number of walks is 1/n(2n choose n) which isn't the case if you multiply by 2^2n which would give you 1/2(2n choose n) to the original probability in the theorem?

Comment: That's a typo.  Their sum, which they appear to compute correctly, is $\frac 12\times \frac {(2n)(2n-1)!}{n\times n!\times (n-1)!}=\frac 12 \times \frac {(2n)!}{n!\times n!}=\frac 12\times \binom {2n}n$.

Comment: @lulu ah brilliant. Thank you so much for your help! been stuck on this for weeks